# Grails 5.2.5 which event is triggered during recompilation

Tags: grails, grails-5

Dear Stackoverflow Gurus,
I am working with Grails for one of the projects and find this technology very fun to work with. During development of some logic however I need to wait for a long time for a restarting of application in order to test the change that is implemented. This means that after changing single line of code I need to wait for 5+ minutes (because of multiple plugins that are loaded during startup of application) to verify it. Also because of custom logic of some service in project for shutdown I am not be able to use some tools like JRebel or DCEVM. So I am trying to find some custom solution for fast restart without loading the plugins again. Auto recompilation of project is enabled. I find that one method of service (that has custom logic for shutdown) annotated with @PreDestroy annotation from JSR standard is executed during recompilation but the methods annotated with @PostConstruct never do. Which event is triggered after Grails Recompilation during initialization? I found that neither methods from BootStrap, nor GrailsAutoConfiguration classes are called (like 'init', 'onStartup', 'doWithApplicationContext').

Comment: "I find that one method of service (that has custom logic for shutdown) annotated with @PreDestroy annotation from JSR standard is executed during recompilation but the methods annotated with @PostConstruct never do" - Are you sure that a method marked with `@PreDestroy` is being executed during recompilation?  I would expect it to be executed during shutdown before the recompilation happens.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the `@PostContruct` methods not being executed and I can't reproduce that.  If you can share a link to a project which demonstrates the problematic behavior I would be happy to investigate.

Comment: I have the following code in the service with custom shutdown logic: `@PostConstruct
    void postConstruct(){
        println("Works!")
    }  @PreDestroy
    void preDestroy() {
        log.info 'preDestroy :>' }`

Comment: The method with `@PreDestroy` is executed during Auto Recompilation of Grails App. But the one with `@PostConstruct` is never called ( I put breakpoint in the method and it is never called during Auto Recompilation).

Comment: It seems that breakpoints for 'println' calls are never reached (maybe because of specifics of 'println'). But breakpoints for other method with '@PostConstruct' annotation was actually called. So this might be one of possibilities to implement hot reload of classes.

Comment: "So this might be one of possibilities to implement hot reload of classes." - It is possible.  I can't reproduce what you are describing but if you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues describing the behavior and linking to a sample app we can investigate.  Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Is it possible that after restart you are not reconnecting the debugging agent?

Comment: What do you mean 'after restart'? I am debugging from IDE context and I am trying to test my changes without the restart (by triggering only recompilation of GRails)

Comment: "I am trying to test my changes without the restart" - The question includes "So I am trying to find some custom solution for fast restart".   I now think I misunderstood.  I am sorry for the confusion.